# Using twitter bootstrap modal to create a gallery with images/content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is what I'm trying to do, but I have no idea how. I've looked at gallery plugins and merging of modal with carousel, but none seem to do what I want.

I have a grid of thumbnails on my site that upon click I want to open a standard bootstrap modal. Once the modal is open, I want the ability to link to the content from the next item, without closing/reopening the modals. So clicking Next/Previous would cycle you through the items in the gallery/grid.

I don't have code to show you at this point. But this plugin is close to what I want to do:
http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

Except I don't want it to open full browser width/height, and would rather it behave more like the standard bootstrap modal. Also, he bootstrap modal gives me a little more control over the content of the modal, rather than stripping it all and simply placing the image as the content.

Any thoughts? help appreciated.

Comment: @realseanp http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Clicking "Launch Image Gallery" in it's default state (without the borderless/full-screen options) seems to do exactly what you describe above... what's missing for you exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

The thumbnails:

```
<div id="thumbHolder">
    <img class="thumb" src="thumbnail.jpg" data-src="largeImage.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" src="thumbnail2.jpg" data-src="largeImage2.jpg">
    <img class="thumb" src="thumbnail3.jpg" data-src="largeImage3.jpg">
</div>
```

The popup styles:

```
#popUp{
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    background:#ffffff;
    display:none;
}
```

Popup HTML

```
<div id="popUp">
    <img class="popImg" src="">
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
    var index = 0;
    var imageCount = $('.thumb').length
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumb').click(function(){
        index = $('.thumb').index($(this));
        var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('.popImg').attr('src', src);
        $('#popUp').fadeIn();  
    });
    $('.next').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (index < imageCount){
            index += 1;
        }
        var nextElement= $('.thumb')[index];
        var src = $(nextElement).attr('data-src');
        $('.popImg').attr('src', src);
    });
    $('.prev').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(index > 0){
            index -= 1;
        }
        var nextElement= $('.thumb')[index];
        var src = $(nextElement).attr('data-src');
        $('.popImg').attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep it works. You will have to edit the styles to make it look pretty, but it works